# Writing one file per group in Pig Latin

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

**The Problem:**
I have numerous files that contain Apache web server log entries.  Those entries are not in date time order and are scattered across the files.  I am trying to use Pig to read a day's worth of files, group and order the log entries by date time, then write them to files named for the day and hour of the entries it contains.

**Setup:**
Once I have imported my files, I am using Regex to get the date field, then I am truncating it to hour.  This produces a set that has the record in one field, and the date truncated to hour in another.  From here I am grouping on the date-hour field.

**First Attempt:**
My first thought was to use the STORE command while iterating through my groups using a FOREACH and quickly found out that is not cool with Pig.

**Second Attempt:**
My second try was to use the MultiStorage() method in the piggybank which worked great until I looked at the file.  The problem is that MulitStorage wants to write all fields to the file, including the field I used to group on.  What I really want is just the original record written to the file.

**The Question:**
So...am I using Pig for something it is not intended for, or is there a better way for me to approach this problem using Pig?  Now that I have this question out there, I will work on a simple code example to further explain my problem.  Once I have it, I will post it here.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, Pig doesn't have a lot of *functionality*. It does the basic stuff, but more times than not I find myself having to write custom UDFs or load/store funcs to get form 95% of the way there to 100% of the way there. I usually find it worth it since just writing a small store function is a lot less Java than a whole MapReduce program.

Your second attempt is really close to what I would do. You should either copy/paste the source code for `MultiStorage` or use inheritance as a starting point. Then, modify the `putNext` method to strip out the group value, but still write to that file. Unfortunately, [`Tuple`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/data/Tuple.html) doesn't have a `remove` or `delete` method, so you'll have to rewrite the entire tuple. Or, if all you have is the original string, just pull that out and output that wrapped in a `Tuple`.

Some general documentation on writing Load/Store functions in case you need a bit more help: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/udf.html#load-store-functions

Comment: Thanks orangeoctopus, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I have written a custom eval UDF, can I assume the process for writing a custom load/store UDF is similar?  I am a bit new to Java...learning as I go.

Comment: It'll be a bit more complicated, but it won't be that bad. One of the best parts of open source is the ability to copy/paste (in a learning sense) from things that perform something similarly. I suggest you try it out and if you have trouble come back and post a new question! I know plenty of guys from a SQL background that didn't know a lick of Java that get by.

Comment: --First, I copied the source of MulitStorage into StoreUDF/MultiStorageUDF.java.
--I then renamed the class and constructors to MultiStorageUDF, and changed the package to MyUDFs.
--I then copied pig.jar into StoreUDF
--Next I did "javac -cp pig.jar MultiStorageUDF.java".
--I then bumped up a direcotry and ran "jar -cf MyUDFs.jar StoreUDF".
  In my .pig file, I have

Comment: -In my pig file I register the jar as "register MyUDFs.jar;" and call the function like "...USING MyUDFs.MultiStorageUDF('$OUTPUT', '0');"  
When I run my job, I get an error message that says "ERROR 1070: Could not resolve MyUDFs.MultiStorageUDF using imports:".  What am I doing wrong?  My UDF compiles just fine, and I am referring to it properly as far as I can tell.

Comment: I just figured it out.  The directory name that contains my .java file and the pig.jar file must have the same name as my package.  Looks like Java basics.

Comment: A quick update for anyone doing this.  I ended up modifying not only putNext to itterate over the group's bag, but also the write method to choose which field in the Tuple to write.