# Apache Pig, Suppress "Output Location Validation Failed" "Output directory ... already exists"

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

After getting help from orangeoctopus with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388510/writing-one-file-per-group-in-pig-latin), I now need to suppress the message "Output Location Validation Failed" "Output directory ... already exists".  I know the directory exists, I want it that way.  I am pretty sure this will be a matter of overriding something in my Storage UDF, but I am having trouble figuring out what.  Totally new to Java so bear with me.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

as far as i know, you cannot reuse a direct output directory. Hadoop prevents it. if i understand correctly, you're dealing with daily logs, therefore, i suggest you set a parent output directory say called output, and set your output directory in the script to be output/daily_date.

Comment: Since I am using a UDF to store, I am pretty sure it is possible to suppress that message.  I just need to figure out what needs to be overridden and where.  My plan is to do exactly what you are saying, except those directories will be created inside the UDF after the "directory already exists" check.

Comment: alright, I'm not familiar with a way doing that inside a storer UDF. if you attend to do what i suggested, why do you need the UDF to do that? why not creating the parent directory once using hadoop fs -mkdir and than send the pig script the run date as a parameter so it will know where to save it?

Comment: Clarke, just curious if you found a solution to this.  I'm facing a similar problem, and would love to know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your output directory before the store operation:

```
rmf $outpath;
```