# Output Location Validation Failed... mapper creating _temporary directory in output folder

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, hdfs

After running

```
hdfs dfs -rm -r -skipTrash hdfs://valid/output/path
hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://valid/output/path
```

and verifying that this output directory does NOT exist, I'm still getting the following error:

```
2016-12-30 23:38:55,290 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 6000:  Output Location Validation Failed for: '/valid/output/path More info to follow:
Output directory hdfs://valid/output/path already exists
```

I've also tried to `fs -rm -r`, `rmr` within my pig script before the `STORE` call, and it errors out claiming that the folder does not exist.

When I `ls` the `hdfs://valid/output/path` output directory, after the pig script errors out, it shows a `_temporary` directory, which contains `attempt_[insert random number]` directories, which in turn seem to contain snappy files. I suspect that the mappers are writing intermediate pieces of data to my output directory. Why would this be and how do I get it to stop?

The relevant headers are as following:

```
SET default_parallel 50;
SET mapreduce.job.queuename my.queue.name;
SET mapreduce.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent 0.7;
SET mapreduce.map.java.opts -Xmx3200m;
SET mapreduce.reduce.java.opts -Xmx6400m;
SET yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts -Xmx6400m;
SET mapreduce.map.memory.mb 4096;
SET mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb 8192;
SET yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb 8192;
SET mapreduce.reduce.maxattempts 20;
```

Already tried solutions in the following to no success:

[Apache Pig, Suppress "Output Location Validation Failed" "Output directory ... already exists"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441755/apache-pig-suppress-output-location-validation-failed-output-directory-a)

Comment: Post the pig script....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [rmf command](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#rmf) and put the path like this

```
rmf /valid/output/path
```

It will not raise an error if the directory does not exist, use it before storing your data.